# how to solve typescript node definition compile errors?

Tags: typescript

In the node.d.ts file installed by the tsd tool i am getting the following compile error :-

```
';' expected
```

for lines that look like :-

```
read(size?: number): string|Buffer;
```

the | is underlined as the issue.

how can i fix this?

Comment: Best that you stick to `1.4` if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i fix this?

You are probably using an older version of the TypeScript compiler. `|` stands for a union type and those came with TypeScript `1.4` and above.